# Curve line without middle anchor point? Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, pen-tool, bezier-curve

I am following along with a tutorial and I noticed the lady hits shift+C on the pen tool path, hovers it in the middle of the path and it curves the path upwards symmetrically. I doesn't look like there was an anchor point in the middle. I tried to do it myself and it didn't work.

[image]

I am guessing this is a new CC feature? Because there is no anchor point in the middle to drag up from. I am guessing I could do this as a workaround?
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't have a copy of CS6 to check, but Shift+C engages the Anchor Point Tool, which when hovered over a path, changes to a little "bend" icon. At least this is how it works in CC [see example](https://imgur.com/F90Jusw). If it doesn't do this, then your workaround seems reasonable.

Comment: Should work in cs6 but your line must have tangent handles to begin with.